# How use socket.io in express routes with node.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using Express with Socket.io in the server side but i can't use out of app.js, i need how to use SocKet.io in Express routes.

**app.js**

```
...  
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('message', (message) => {
        console.log("Message Received: " + message);
        io.emit('message', {type:'new-message', text: message});    
    });  
});
...
```

this work ok, but i have other routes where configure my methods, POST, GET ... EX

**routesActividad.js**

```
...
function http(){ 

  this.configActividad= function(app){
    // get actividades by id
    app.get('/actividad/:NUM_ID_EMPLEADO', function(req, res) {
    //... code here...//
      .then(function (actividad) {              
        res.json(actividad);
      }).catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
    })

   app.post('/actividad/', function(req, res){
    // code here //
   })

   app.put('/actividad/', function(req, res){
    // code here //
   })
  }
}

module.exports = new http();
```

how i can use socket in routesActividad.js and other routes like this, for use emit or scoket.on y this routes

**app.js**

```
...
var routesActividad = require('./routes/routesActividad');
    routesActividad.configActividad(app);
// more routes
...
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you just need to pass the IO instance by parameter to your external module:

**app.js**

```
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);
let actividad = require('routesActividad')(io);
```

**routesActividad.js:**

```
function http(io){ 

   //put the IO stuff wherever you want inside functions or outside



  this.configActividad= function(app){
    // get actividades by id
    app.get('/actividad/:NUM_ID_EMPLEADO', function(req, res) {
    //... code here...//
      .then(function (actividad) {              
        res.json(actividad);
      }).catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
    })

   app.post('/actividad/', function(req, res){
    // code here //
   })

   app.put('/actividad/', function(req, res){
    // code here //
   })
  }
}

module.exports = http; //Removed new statement
```

Comment: this work for me, thanks!! it was very helpful @Gomosoft